# Copiar uma palavra de uma coluna para o fim

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho varios registos no sql por exemplo

```
almedia,jose costa santos
```

e quero alterar o valor para:

```
jose costa santos almeida
```

Ou seja quero pegar o sobrenome que está no começo(antes da vírgula) e colocar ele no final, porém não sei como fazer.

Comment: Qual base de dados você está usando?

Comment: O ideal é você receber o valor da forma que está e depois fazer o tratamento invertendo os valores.

Comment: estou a usar o sql server express

Comment: Se a persistência dos dados for em um único campo, terá que construir uma função para corrigir a entrada no banco.

Comment: sim é um unico campo

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o [CharIndex()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186323(v=sql.120).aspx) e o [SubString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187748(v=sql.120).aspx) para fazer o que precisa.

Primeiro devemos achar o caracter delimitador, no seu caso a vírgula.

Após isso iremos buscar o que vem antes e após a virgula, desta forma:

```
select
    Substring(nome, Charindex(',', nome)+1, LEN(nome)) as Nome,
    Substring(nome, 1,Charindex(',', nome)-1) as LastName,
from Pessoas
```

Agora, para o que você precisa, basta concatenar os dois, ficando assim:

```
select
    Substring(nome, Charindex(',', nome)+1, LEN(nome)) + ' ' + Substring(nome, 1,Charindex(',', nome)-1) as Nome
 from pessoas
```

[Neste Link](http://trabalhandocomsqlserver.blogspot.com.br/2010/06/usando-as-funcoes-substring-charindex-e.html) possui um pequeno tutorial das funções.

Answer (score 3):

O @Randrade explicou bem e deu a [solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111266/3084) para um `SELECT` , mas caso você realmente queira alterar e não simplesmente selecionar, acredito que um código correto é o seguinte:

```
update tabela set nome = 
substring(nome,charindex(',',nome)+1,len(nome)) + ' ' +
substring(nome,1 ,charindex(',',nome)-1)
```

Segue o mesmo conceito por ele explicado para o `SELECT`

E uma dica importante de quem já passou muito aperto é de sempre antes de um update que afeta muitos registros, testar a query de um `SELECT` correspondente pois um update incorreto ou acidental pode complicar sua vida e levar a perda de dados .

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/53961)

Comment: @cantoni Não entendi... respondi com o código que acredito realizar a ação que ele deseja "alterar o valor para jose costa santos almeida" , no caso update e não select pois ele disse que deseja alterar e não exibir .

Comment: Olá Diego, sinalizei, pois isso mais parece um comentário do que uma resposta. Como sugestão, tente dar um enriquecida na sua resposta. Ao invés de deixar somente o código, explique ao AP como este código resolve o problema. Exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111266/3084

Comment: @cantoni O Randrade explicou tudo , minha resposta é um complemento a dele , mas vou detalhar melhor

Comment: Esse é o caminho Diego. :-)

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxílio @cantoni !

Comment: @cantoni nada a ver.

Answer (score 0):

Para o seu caso terá que criar uma função para tal efeito.
A função receberá o nome, e fazer a busca até a virgula (que deverá estar no campo), copiar para uma variável a parte até a virgula, e o restante para outra variável e concatenar a sequencia correta. 
Simulando

```
variavel1= copia até a virgula;
variavel2= copia do restante após a virgula;
resultado = concatenar variavel2 e variavel1;
```

A ideia é esta.

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer isso com a junção de duas funções:

`substring_index(string, delimitador, número da ocorrência do delimitador)` que procura a string que você quer e faz a separação.

e

`concat(string1, string2, string3, ...)` para juntar as palavras.

### SELECIONAR

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOME, ',', -1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOME, ',', 1)) 
FROM 
     TABELA
```

### ALTERAR

```
UPDATE
    TABELA
SET 
    NOME = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOME, ',', -1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOME, ',', 1))
```

### Saída

> José Costa Santos Almeida

Comment: ola internato fiz isto para teste e chegui a mesma soluçao 
declare @nam varchar(300)
set @nam='Almeida,José Costa Santos '
select right(@nam, len(@nam)-charindex(',',@nam)) + ' ' +left(@nam, charindex(',',@nam)-1) as frist

Answer (score 0):

SOLUÇÃO

```
declare @nam varchar(300) 
set @nam='Almeida,José Costa Santos ' 
select right(@nam, len(@nam)-charindex(',',@nam)) + ' ' +left(@nam, charindex(',',@nam)-1) as frist
```